# Binding a ListViewItems Visibility/Value to a ListViews-DataContext Item-Property?

Tags: c#, xaml, triggers, uwp, styles

I try to set the Visibility of a ListViewItem by a Property of the related Item, all of this happens inside my Listbox-Style. My xaml looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="SideDrawerListViewStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <c:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=DataContext.ItemVisibility}"
                                           Value="Collapsed">
                        <c:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </c:DataTriggerBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the ListView which uses the Style I made

```
<ListView Style="{StaticResource SideDrawerListViewStyle}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SideDrawerElementList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSideDrawerElement, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedSideDrawerIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

While this is my ListView-Items ViewModel

```
public class SideDrawerElementViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _text;
    public string Text
    {
        get => _text;
        set => Set(ref _text, value);
    }

    private string _glyph;
    public string Glyph
    {
        get => _glyph;
        set => Set(ref _glyph, value);
    }

    private Visibility _itemvisibility;
    public Visibility ItemVisibility
    {
        get => _itemvisibility;
        set => Set(ref _itemvisibility, value);
    }
    public string sIV
    { get => ItemVisibility.ToString(); }

    public SideDrawerElementViewModel(string content, string glyph, Visibility visibility)
    {
        Text = content;
        Glyph = glyph;
        ItemVisibility = visibility;
    }
}
```

I don't get any error, but the Visibility-Value of my ListView-Item gets never called. I checked twice to set it Collapsed. Also tried to replace it by a boolean or string value, but it did not change anything.

Since I'm writing for UWP I'm using Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed so 'xmlns:i' is 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity' and 'xmlns:c' is 'Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core'. Also I'm using MvvmLight

Comment: I haven't checked your code carefully but just a simple question. When you are using TemplatedParent you have already assigned the datacontext, why you need to write something like this Path=DataContext.ItemVisibility to specify datacontext again?

Comment: Actually this was only the last of the many tries which had failed. Recently I solved the problem by using a collectionviewsource, still a possibility for binding the itemcontainer-property to an item-property would be appreciated

Comment: So what about SideDrawerElementList code and how you changed the property. I haven't tested whether a listviewitem can respond to behavior but any controls in the item can obviouly hide or show as far as I know. Such as this msdn case mentiond: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22f4c524-f428-4c07-b4b2-8d9c38a61cef/how-to-change-visibility-of-a-textblock-based-on-the-tap-event-using-only-xaml?forum=wpdevelop Something should be used to trigger the ChangePropertyAction, not just setting the property you mentioned.